# How to keep Apache server fulfilling request when closing the browser?

Tags: php, browser

I intend to write N-queens solution to a file in PHP. As the time elapsed for large N is so long, I want to place PHP code on the server, and then request for that page. Is it possible that when I close the tab in the browser, the server keep calculating and write to a file to fulfil my request ? Then later on I would check the file to see the results. If  not possible, any suggestions for this problem is appreciated.

Comment: run the script in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) and [set_time_limit](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

```
ignore_user_abort(true); // continue to run after client disconnects
set_time_limit(0); // infinite time limit
```

Rather than an infinite time limit, you could estimate the number of seconds the script will need and pad more time on to it. That way the script won't have a chance to hang the process.